# Batch file variable filenames: make timestamp filename within a for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I am trying to run a batch of Lighthouse audits from the command line and output the results to JSON files. To ensure they don't overwrite one another, each file name needs to be unique. I would like to use the timestamp as the filename ideally. I have been through many other Stack questions on a similar topic, but I cannot get this to work. I am currently using the below code, written within a batch file and called from Windows command line:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\urls.txt) DO (
    set dte=!DATE:/=-%!
    set tme=!TIME::=-%!
    set tme=!%tme:.=-%!
    ECHO Line is: %%a
    lighthouse %%a --quiet --chrome-flags=" --headless" --output=json --output-path=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\json_logs\!dte!!tme!.json
)
```

The first file produced has the correct name all subsequent JSONs have the literal name: '!dte!!tme!', and do overwrite one another. If you run the Lighthouse command outside of a for loop it executes perfectly, I'm aware that variables don't update within a for loop but I thought !var! could be used to counter this. The for loop iterates through a list of URLs stored in urls.txt, auditing each of them in turn and returning a JSON file.

Current outcome: `!dte!!tme!.json`
Desired oucome: `08-10-201913-55-12-07.json`, `08-10-201913-56-14-00.json` etc.
[image: Image demonstrating current file output]

If anybody knows how to amend this to achieve the correct outcome I would be very grateful.

The urls.txt contains a list of URLs, each on a new line:

> ```
> https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743
> https://www.bbc.com/mundo
> https://regex101.com/
> https://www.bbc.co.uk/news
> ```

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the expansion without exiting the loop as you intended.. Note I have added a timeout of millisecond here to ensure we have a different time each time. `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500> nul`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%userprofile%\Desktop\Croud_DS_1\Lighthouse_Project\urls.txt) DO (
     set dte=!date:/=-!
     set tme=!time::=-!
     set tme=!tme:.=-!
     set tme=!tme:,=-!
     echo Line is: %%a
     lighthouse "%%a" --quiet --chrome-flags=" --headless" --output=json --output-path=%userprofile%\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\json_logs\!dte!_!tme!.json
     ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500> nul
)
```

Please take note, I took the liberty of adding an underscore to make sure the date and time format is readable, so you'll have `YYYY-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-ms`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, the result is still one file with the correct naming, then the rest overwriting one another with file name "!dte!_!tme!". Additionally, the console is now issuing a warning: "Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of batch script."

Comment: @DarceyBM Please try the amended code as is and let me know the outcome. Do not amend anything in my script. Copy and paste as is into a new script. Also do not name the script lighthouse, call it something like `Darce_lighthouse.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\urls.txt) DO (
set dte=!DATE:/=-!
set tme=!TIME::=-!
set tme=!tme:.=-!
ECHO Line is: %%a
echo lighthouse "%%a" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless" --output=json --output-path="C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\json_logs\!dte!!tme!.json"
Timeout 2 >NUL
)
Timeout -1 >NUL
```

This uses the exact content from your `urls.txt` example. I have added `@Echo Off` at the top to reduce screen clutter, and an `echo` in front of your `lighthouse` command so that it displays instead of runs. Additionally I included a couple of `timeout`s to both simulate a short timespan, *(as the command is being `echo`'ed not ran)*, and to give you an opportunity to read the output at the end.

Here's the output from the above to prove my case:

```
Line is: https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743
lighthouse "https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2643743" --quiet --chrome-flags="--hea
dless" --output=json --output-path="C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Pro
ject\json_logs\08-10-201916-12-42-93.json"
Line is: https://www.bbc.com/mundo
lighthouse "https://www.bbc.com/mundo" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless" --out
put=json --output-path="C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\json_lo
gs\08-10-201916-12-44-14.json"
Line is: https://regex101.com/
lighthouse "https://regex101.com/" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless" --output=
json --output-path="C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\json_logs\0
8-10-201916-12-46-12.json"
Line is: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news
lighthouse "https://www.bbc.co.uk/news" --quiet --chrome-flags="--headless" --ou
tput=json --output-path="C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folder\Lighthouse_Project\json_l
ogs\08-10-201916-12-48-21.json"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Your issue, as originally stated, was the inclusion of `%` characters in your initial `set` syntax, as you can see from the provided output.

Comment: I have updated and reworded my answer above, to now use the four lines you've provided for `urls.txt` and the same line `3` command, to hopefully satisfy you that my initial statement was correct and your typographical error when setting `tme` was the timestamp issue. You can clearly see in my provided output that the correct dates and times are being sent to the lighthouse command!